# Java Sorting Object According to Attribute

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was having some problem when trying to sort array list of objects. Basically I have populated an object list and the sample data:

```
name: UNIFORMITY
date: Tue Oct 30 02:48:32 GMT+00:00 2018
name: ROI
date: Wed Oct 31 02:48:32 GMT+00:00 2018
name: UNIFORMITY
date: Wed Oct 31 02:48:32 GMT+00:00 2018
```

I populated the array list with the code below:

```
CalibrationHistoryEntity object3 = new CalibrationHistoryEntity();
    object3.setCalibrationName("ROI");
    try {
        object3.setCalibrationDate(dt.parse("Oct 31 02:48:32 GMT+00:00 2018"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    allCalibrationList.add(object3);
```

Then, what I wanted to do is to sort the array list such that for the object with same name, I only get the largest date and put it back to the array but I have no ideas how to do it. Any ideas?

My desired output will be like this:

```
name: ROI
date: Wed Oct 31 02:48:32 GMT+00:00 2018
name: UNIFORMITY
date: Wed Oct 31 02:48:32 GMT+00:00 2018
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Any ideas on how to do it?" Yes, but more importantly, do *you* have any ideas?  And if so, how did it not work to your satisfaction.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I am not sure on how or where to start :(

Comment: What is CalibrationHistoryEntity ? can you provide the class.

Comment: @Rab It is an object class with CalibrationName and CalibrationDate as attributes!

Comment: Yes, I need the class, I want to know what Object they are. Provide the class and I will fiddle around with the code.

Comment: @Rab Updated question!

Comment: What's `PrimaryKey`? and the other annotations?

Comment: It is actually an object class with the two attributes mentioned above. The reason for those annotation is because I am dealing with SQLite which I do not want to post it here as it will make the situation even more complex :(

Comment: Okay, What is `dt`?

Comment: And if I'm understanding you correctly you want only the largest date of the same data to be there? so no duplicates and if there are only store the largest date one?

Comment: dt is SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");  Yeah for each calibration name, I only wanted to store the largest date

Comment: @Rab I think I managed to resolved it already. What I did was first sort them in descending order. Then I check for calibration name before insert into another array. If existed, then do not insert.

Comment: That won't work, I am already writing a solution.

Comment: @dummygg - check my answer below please. i didn't notice the exact names of your inner attributes. but the solution works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following simple block will give you what you need.
It is also efficient because it is O(n)

```
    Map<String, CalibrationHistoryEntity> unique = new HashMap<String, CalibrationHistoryEntity>();

    for (CalibrationHistoryEntity k : allCalibrationList) {
        CalibrationHistoryEntity temp = unique.getOrDefault(k.Name, null);

        if (temp == null || temp.time.before(k.time))
            unique.put(k.Name, k);
    }
```

In the following step we pull the results ... i am doing some sort by name as well (optional)

```
    // Optional but you can sort by name :
    Stream<CalibrationHistoryEntity> result = unique.values().stream()
            .sorted((a, b) -> {
                return a.Name.compareTo(b.Name);
            });
```

Now let's print results (or use as you wish):

```
    // Now you can print
    result.forEach(k -> {
        System.out.println("Name: " + k.Name + ", Time: " + k.time);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this is :

1. grouping by name
2. for each groups get the maximum date value.
3. add each maximum to the new list

For example with stream

```
 final Map<String, List<CalibrationHistoryEntity>> groupingByName= allCalibrationList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CalibrationHistoryEntity::getCalibrationName));
 final List<CalibrationHistoryEntity> list = groupingByName.values()
            .stream().map(it -> Collections.max(it, Comparator.comparing(CalibrationHistoryEntity::getCalibrationDate)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have done writing the method for you to sort the List here it is

```
    ListIterator<CalibrationHistoryEntity> listIterator = allCalibrationList.listIterator();
    while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        CalibrationHistoryEntity calibrationHistoryEntity = listIterator.next();
        //Get all the index
        List<Integer> indexes = findAllByName(allCalibrationList, calibrationHistoryEntity.getCalibrationName());
        if (indexes.size() > 1) {
            List<CalibrationHistoryEntity> calibrationHistoryEntities = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index : indexes) {
                calibrationHistoryEntities.add(allCalibrationList.get(index));
            }
            //Sort by biggest time
            calibrationHistoryEntities.sort(Comparator.comparing(CalibrationHistoryEntity::getCalibrationDate).reversed());
            for (int i = 1; i < calibrationHistoryEntities.size(); i++) {
                //Remove others
                listIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

and the method to get all the index

```
/**
 * gets all the index via the name
 */
public static List<Integer> findAllByName(List<CalibrationHistoryEntity> allCalibrationList, String name) {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CalibrationHistoryEntity calibrationHistoryEntity : allCalibrationList) {
        if (calibrationHistoryEntity.getCalibrationName().equals(name)) {
            indexes.add(allCalibrationList.indexOf(calibrationHistoryEntity));
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

and I made the input via

```
    String[] names = {"UNIFORMITY", "Roi", "UNIFORMITY"};
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date[] dates = new Date[0];
    try {
        dates = new Date[]{dt.parse("Oct 31 02:48:32 GMT+00:00 2018"),
                dt.parse("Oct 31 02:48:25 GMT+00:00 2018"),
                dt.parse("Oct 31 02:48:37 GMT+00:00 2018")};
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<CalibrationHistoryEntity> allCalibrationList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        String name = names[i];
        Date date = dates[i];
        CalibrationHistoryEntity calibrationHistoryEntity = new CalibrationHistoryEntity();
        calibrationHistoryEntity.setCalibrationName(name);
        calibrationHistoryEntity.setCalibrationDate(date);
        allCalibrationList.add(calibrationHistoryEntity);
    }
```

This is the output

```
Name: Roi Time:Wed Oct 31 05:48:25 GMT+03:00 2018
Name: UNIFORMITY Time:Wed Oct 31 05:48:37 GMT+03:00 2018
```

Comment: this is not good from performance point of view. you can give a solution with O(n) instead